# Nest.js and DynamoDB: Should I use the putIem method or the updateItem if my request errors with my Interceptor and service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs

I have a [Interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors).ts I created, in it I am passing request information to a table in [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)

Interceptor.ts

```
export class ReqResLoggerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        const preventReqResLog: boolean = this.reflector.get<boolean>('preventReqResLog', context.getHandler());

        const req: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const { statusCode } = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        const { originalUrl, method, params, query, headers, body } = req;
        const isHealthRoute: boolean = originalUrl.endsWith('health/detailed') || originalUrl.endsWith('health');

        const timeStamp: string = this.dSUtil.getCurrentTS();
        const requestDetails: DSRequestRequestDetails = new DSRequestRequestDetails();
        req.body.id = headers.awsrequestid as string;

        requestDetails.appName = body.appName;
        requestDetails.customerName = body.customerName;
        requestDetails.originalUrl = originalUrl;
        requestDetails.method = method;
        requestDetails.params = params;
        requestDetails.id = req.body.id;
        requestDetails.type = EItemType.REQUEST;
        requestDetails.query = query;
        requestDetails.headers = headers;
        requestDetails.requestState = EDSRequestRequestDetails.INPROGRESS; // in progress
        requestDetails.timeStamp = timeStamp;

        try {
                (async () => {
                    await this.dsDynamoDBService
                        .putItem({
                            TableName: this.dsConfig.aws.dynamoDB.table,
                            Item: requestDetails
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            this.logService.error(error);
                        });
                })();
            }
            (req as any).isLogReqRes = !preventReqResLog;
        } catch (error) {
            this.logService.error(error);
        }

        return next.handle().pipe(
        tap((data) => {
            try {
                if (data.success) {
                    requestDetails.requestState = EDSRequestRequestDetails.COMPLETE;
                    (async () => {
                        await this.dsDynamoDBService
                            .putItem({
                                TableName: this.dsConfig.aws.dynamoDB.table,
                                Item: requestDetails
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                this.logService.error(error);
                            });
                    })();
                }
            } catch (error) {
                this.logService.error(error);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

}

Essentially in every service my controllers are using I have a catch block like this:

`doc_generation.service`

```
@Injectable()
export class DSDocGenerationService {
    constructor(

        private readonly dsDynamoDBService: DSDynamoDBService,
        private readonly dynamoDBMethodsUtils: DynamoDBMethodsUtils
    ) {}

    async generateDoc(docGenReq: DSDocGenerateRequestModel, dataRoute: boolean): Promise<DSDocGenerateResponseModel> {
        const tableItem: DSTableItem<DocumentUrlMap> = await this.prepareTableItem(docGenReq);
        const docGenResponse: DSDocGenerateResponseModel = new DSDocGenerateResponseModel();
        try {
            ...try code
        } catch (error) {
            this.dynamoDBMethodsUtils.handleDsDynamoDBServiceError(docGenReq.id);
            this.logService.error(error);
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.message);
        }
    }
```

which if it errors goes to this error handler which updates DynamoDB.

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamoDBMethodsUtils {
    constructor(
        private readonly dsDynamoDBService: DSDynamoDBService,
        private readonly dsConfig: DSConfig
    ) {}

/**
 * Function to update audit information to DynamoDBService when service errors
 *
 * @param {string} id
 * @return {*}  {Promise<void>}
 * @memberof DynamoDBMethodsUtils
 */
async handleDsDynamoDBServiceError(id: string): Promise<void> {
    const requestDetails: DSRequestRequestDetails = new DSRequestRequestDetails();
    requestDetails.id = id;
    requestDetails.requestState = EDSRequestRequestDetails.ERROR;
    await this.dsDynamoDBService.putItem({
        TableName: this.dsConfig.aws.dynamoDB.table,
        Item: requestDetails
    });
}
```

}

So do I need to be explicit in updating my tables with this [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) method instead of the above? I mean every request starts about with the `requestDetails.id = req.body.id set in the Interceptor` and that is part of Item property.

And the same goes for the `putItem` in `return next.handle().pipe` call? Should that be an [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) as well?

Any help would be appreciated.